# Proof for the number of basic vectors are the same for any basis

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces

> If $v_1, ... , v_m$ and $w_1, ... , w_n$ are both bases for the same vector space, then $m
> =n$

**Proof**

Assume that there are more $w$'s than $v$'s, ie., $n>m$

$$
w_1=a_{11}v_1+....+a_{m1}v_m
$$
Similarly, each $w$ is a linear combination of the $v$'s
$$
\begin{bmatrix}w_1&w_2&\dots&w_n\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}v_1&v_2&\dots&v_m\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}a_{11}&\dots&a_{1n}\\
\vdots&&\vdots\\
a_{m1}&\cdots&a_{mn}\end{bmatrix}\iff W=VA
$$
Then it says "$A$ is a short-wide matrix, since we assumed $n>m$. So $Ax= 0$ has a nonzero solution"

How come $n>m$ alone says anything about the system ?

I understand that if $rank(A)<n$(not Full rank), then $Ax=0$ must have nonzero solutions, but how can I know about the rank of the matrix $A$ from the given details ?

**Reference:** Page 170, Dimension of Vector Spaces, Introduction to Linear Algebra - Ed 5, Gilbert Strang

Comment: Put $A$ into echelon form, to see that $Ax=0$ has a non-zero solution.

Comment: What is $r$ in your question?

Comment: @AnikBhowmick $rank(A)$

Comment: You always have $r\le \min(n,m)$ so in this case $r\le m$. The rank can never exceed the number of rows or columns of the matrix.

Comment: @Christoph In order to use “rank-nullity” you already need to know that “dimension of a vector space” is a well-defined concept and this is what the question is about.

Comment: @Christoph how do you know $rank(A)\leq m<n$ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When row reducing $A$ to row echelon form, the number of pivots (which is the rank of $A$) can never exceed the number of columns or the number of rows of $A$. Hence, when $A$ is an $m\times n$ matrix with $m<n$, you can have at most $m$ pivot variables in $Ax=0$, leaving you at least $n-m>0$ free variables. Hence there is a non-zero solution to $Ax=0$ that can be found by choosing non-zero values for the free variables and solving for the pivot variables.

Answer (score -1):

**Hint**: $Ax=0$ has a unique solution iff $A$ is square and has full rank. Can you proceed now?

Comment: Full rank $\iff $ $rank(A)=n$ right ? That is mentioned in OP. but where in the question we can get information about the rank of the coefficient matrix $A$ ?

Comment: How do you define the rank without knowing that the number of elements in a basis is invariant?

Comment: @egreg Then the word $rank$ shouldn't be used in the first place

Comment: This is wrong, $Ax=0$ has a unique solution iff the rank is equal to the number of columns, while the number of rows can be greater than the number of columns

Comment: @egreg: the rank can be defined as the order of the greater non vanishing minor of the matrix

Comment: @enzotib Which requires determinants…

Comment: @egreg: and so? should we not assume knowledge of determinants?

Comment: @enzotib The present question is at a much more elementary level.

Comment: @egreg: more elementary level? I teach mathematics in a second semester of the first year of engineering, and one of the first things we do in linear algebra are matrices and determinants

Comment: @enzotib The OP is mentioning Strang, which has a different order of topics. In my course determinants come quite late, because I think they're not really a useful tool for computing (or even defining) the rank of a matrix.

Comment: @egreg OK, I usually follow a different approach